# Any javascript (web-based) wysiwyg editor that produces xsl:fo

Tags: javascript, xslt, editor, wysiwyg, xsl-fo

I am having a hard time finding on OSS or commercial web-based (javascript) WYSIWYG* editor that produces XSL:FO. Would I would love to have the editor capable of doing...

- The user is presented with common text-editor interface, not unlike the editor I am currently typing into to submit this question to SO.
- The user is able to define all the structural components afforded by XSL:FO (new pages, new regions).  Any "simplification" the editor can do (such as handling some of the implicit XSL:FO formatting necessary to place graphics and the like) would be helpful
- Ability to create inline areas, such as lists and tables, add graphics, etc
- Ability to style within the confines of the XSL:FO specification

(*) Since it is a WYSIWYG editor, there must be an ability to preview the document being created.  Since XSL:FO requires an XLS:FO processor to translate into documents (RTF, PDF, etc etc) I would expect there to be a means to select which document type I would like to render, select "preview", and that document be rendered for preview (in an iframe, another window, whatever).  I would expect this to require a server-side XSL:FO processor component as well.  A bonus would be a "default" auto-preview that sends an AJAX request to the server to update the preview during a users content-creation "pause" (if the user doesn't add content for 5 seconds, auto-preview).

Comment: "Since XSL:FO requires an XSLT to meaningfully translate it to a document (XHTML, RTF, PDF, etc etc)..." sounds a little odd. The most common way to produce XSL-FO is to apply an XSLT stylesheet to an XML document (for example a DocBook document). But once you have the XSL-FO markup you don't need XSLT, you need software that can render it (an XSL-FO formatter, such as [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)). Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: It is not you who misunderstood, it was I who did not remember the technologies quite right - I have updated my question to reflect this inaccuracy of mine.  Thank you for pointing that out.  My question, however, remains.  I would prefer not to have to make this intermediary XSTL translation from a DocBook or [X]HTML editor if possible, but rather directly generate the XLS:FO at the editor.

Comment: Hi, sorry to be a nag, but the text is still not quite clear. A FO processor renders FO markup into paginated output, such as PDF (or RTF). But using a FO processor to produce XHTML sounds really strange. And you should fix the "to convert the XSL:FO with the XSLT" passage too.

Comment: I don't take it as nagging, I appreciate accuracy - especially when it helps me solidify my understanding.  Thank you, the question was updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), both let you control the features exposed to the user, then use a serverside library to convert the HTML into XML:FO. I was only able to find one library that does this, [html2fo](http://html2fo.sourceforge.net/), but I don't think it supports the full range of features you're looking for.

Comment: I've used TinyMCE in the past, and currently use FCK, as web based editors.  As you point out, it creates HTML content.  The problem I run into with this is that it doesn't always produce perfectly.  So before sending it through an XSLT->XSL:FO->doc I have to add a cleanup routine.  So it turns out to by something like tagsoup->XSLT->XSL:FO->doc.  But even then, it doesn't always work 100% - and the problems always seem to stem around the initial HTML formatting.  I really don't want to play cat/mouse with the HTML spec as things progress either.

Comment: @Steve TinyMCE I has an option to generate strict markup - not sure about FCK. Checkout http://www.gethifi.com/blog/how-to-produce-xhtml-10-strict-markup-with-tinymce . I'd also watch this question, you might be able to use one of the libs posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594310/how-mature-is-htmlcss-now-in-relation-to-generating-reports-for-printing

Comment: Nice link, thanks.  If I have to continue the HTML->... route, I'll take a look at this over FCK.  I think I would still prefer to write to a document-neutral format like XSL:FO if possible and render in various formats from there.  I am open to have my mind changed, but other than lack of existing editors I don't see a technical downside from this approach but I do have practical experience problems with the way I'm currently doing business.