# how mature is HTML+CSS now in relation to generating reports for printing?

Tags: php, javascript, html, printing

I'm considering creating all the reports of a series of desktop business apps directly to html. Most of the reports are tables (maybe compound reports), headers, footers, etc. (no images, vector graphics, etc.).

After a search in SO, I've read lots of post regarding problems with page breaks and things like that (I don't need pixel positioning at all, but yes control at page breaks).

**For example, let's say I have a big table with currency values and I need the last row of the table per page to display the running totals at that point.. it is something feasible to do easily or I will run in lots of trouble?**

What technologies can help me here?

- HTML5
- Javascript
- CSS
- PHP Librarys
- JQuery

Some notes:

- The html will be displayed with the chrome or firefox engine embeded, so the diferences between browsers it's not a problem for me.
- I can have the php preprocessor embedded if that helps to generate more easily the reports, I'm just looking fot the best technology at hand to make the work well..
- I'm tired of report generators with "WYSIWYG" designers (Crystal Report, FastReport, ReportBuilder, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: I would say your main problem is having HTML+CSS as a pageless medium, being aware of page types/heights to break properly, etc...

Comment: If you're asking a question regarding the maturity of HTML, you may want to avoid talking about HTML5 at this point... :)

Comment: Yes, please note I admit that I don't have a lot of experience with HTML and web technologies (Javascript, HTML5, CSS, etc.) but yes with desktop applications, databases, business logics, accounting, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We made the exact move you're thinking about almost a year ago and haven't looked back.  Most communication with our client is over the web, so it's been a perfect fit.  They can view html outputs easily on our website, and can generate pdf's of the page (server side) whenever necessary.  The program we use for pdf conversion is a free, easy-to-use, open-source project called [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

**Where we are is great, but getting here was difficult.**

Deciding which pdf engine to use was a long, painful process.  The short of it is that HTML is for viewing pages on the internet, not for viewing pages on paper.  Page-breaks will be the bane of your existence in this game -- you literally have to measure each page and create your own clean-looking breaks for every single report *(otherwise, all html-to-pdf converters out there will just keep rendering the document onto the next page as it if encountered no page-break at all).*  Further complicating the matter is that every html-to-pdf engine out there handles this sh*t differently and you'll have to write a tailored solution to test each one to see if it meets your individual needs.

**Now, the good news:**

You can save yourself a lot of trouble by heeding my advice and going with [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) for your finalized reporting outputs.  This little program is simply amazing -- it uses a webkit engine, renders CSS/javascript accurately, has header/footer control, optionally creates a table-of-contents page, and (most importantly) consistently produces excellent looking pdf's without having to customize your code base.  It also has a variety of great command line switches, *and it is very, very fast.*  I say again: **it is very, very fast.**

Best of all, it's a command line tool that can be used in batch processing.  And did I mention that it's really, really fast?

Answer (score 6):

Browser support for printing is generally terrible.  However, there are other tools, notably [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) (which is not free) and [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) (which *is* free) that can generate PDF output from XML/HTML plus CSS.  Prince even supports JavaScript though I don't have any experience with it.

I've got a Java back end in my current application, so for me Flying Saucer works fine for simple reports. I pre-process an HTML template with FreeMarker and then run the result through Flying Saucer.  It's got a surprisingly smart rendering engine.

The [CSS3 Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) spec (well, proposed spec) has all sorts of cool stuff in it but they're almost totally unimplemented in the browsers. Even the CSS2 paged media stuff is only supported half-heartedly.

Comment: Very nice answer. HTML and CSS are not bad. It's all about specific implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of Prince, you might look into DocRaptor. DocRaptor is another [HTML to PDF conversion](http://docraptor.com) application. It uses Prince XML, and handles CSS better than comparable programs.

It isn't free, but offers a free 30 day trial for all accounts, so there's no harm in trying it out, at least.

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)